Move reviews below the upsell and cross-sell section in Woocommerce
I am working with woocommerce plugin. I currently have product virtual reviews using Faview plugin, and then it's related products, complete the set and you may also like section in product detail page. I would like to change the display order. I want to display product, it's related products and then it's reviews. I have tried changing the priority in functions.php but it doesn't work:
add_action( 'init', 'move_related_products_before_tabs' );
function move_related_products_before_tabs( ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 5 );
}


// Remove the default reviews hook
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10);

// Add reviews below upsell and cross-sell sections
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_move_reviews_section', 20);

function custom_move_reviews_section() {
    // Check if WooCommerce is active
    if (!function_exists('woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs')) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Output the reviews section
    woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs();
}


thank you for your help. The code goes in the function.php file of the active child theme but it is not working.
